# How optimize query

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

How can i optimize this query ?

```
CREATE TABLE rechercherefppv3bis_tmp
( `id` varchar(25) KEY,   `dateMaj` datetime DEFAULT NULL,   `type` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,   `nom` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,   `prenom` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,   `adresseLigne2` varchar(38) DEFAULT NULL,   `adresseLigne3` varchar(38) DEFAULT NULL,   `adresseLigne4` varchar(38) DEFAULT NULL,   `adresseLigne5` varchar(38) DEFAULT NULL,   `adresseLigne6` varchar(38) DEFAULT NULL,   `adresseLigne7` varchar(38) DEFAULT NULL,   `emailPrincipal` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,   `telephonePrincipal` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,   `lignes4` text,   `lignes6` text,   `numeros` text,   `adresses` text,   `numProcuration` text,   `numReexpedition` text, `cp` varchar(255), `isDGP` boolean NULL, `civilite` varchar(255) NULL,`codeCivilite` int(10) NULL , `coclico` varchar(8) NULL , `certificationStatut` varchar(255) NULL , `siret` varchar(14) NULL , `nomSociete` varchar(255) NULL )
AS (
    SELECT
                    u.id,
                    str_to_date(GREATEST(u.dateMaj, ifnull(a.dateMaj, '1970-01-01 08:00:00'), ifnull(t.dateMaj, '1970-01-01 08:00:00'), ifnull(m.dateMaj, '1970-01-01 08:00:00')),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as dateMaj,
                    u.type as type,
                    u.nom as nom,
                    u.prenom as prenom,
                    a.ligne1 as adresseLigne1,
                    a.ligne2 as adresseLigne2,
                    a.ligne3 as adresseLigne3,
                    a.ligne4 as adresseLigne4,
                    a.ligne5 as adresseLigne5,
                    a.ligne6 as adresseLigne6,
                    a.ligne7 as adresseLigne7,
                    m.adresse as emailPrincipal,
                    t.numero AS telephonePrincipal,
                    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ads.ligne4 SEPARATOR ';') as lignes4,
                    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ads.ligne6 SEPARATOR ';') as lignes6,
                    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ts.numero SEPARATOR ';') as numeros,
                    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ms.adresse SEPARATOR ';') as adresses,
                    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT pp.idOrigine SEPARATOR ';') as numProcuration,
                    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT rc.numero SEPARATOR ';') as numReexpedition,
                    SUBSTRING_INDEX(a.ligne6,' ',1) AS cp,
                    case when ctp1.idContratDGP is null then false else true end as isDGP,
                    u.niveauAdhesion,
                    u.civilite,
                    u.codeCivilite,
                    u.certificationStatus as certificationStatut,
                    u.coclico,
                    cr.nom as nomSociete,
                    cr.siret as siret
                FROM ccu_user_v3bis  u
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN ccu_adresse_v3bis a ON a.idUser = u.id AND a.principale = 1
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN ccu_email_v3bis m ON m.idUser = u.id AND m.principal = 1
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN ccu_telephone_v3bis t ON t.idUser = u.id AND t.principal = 1
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN ccu_adresse_v3bis ads ON ads.idUser = u.id
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN ccu_email_v3bis ms ON ms.idUser = u.id
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN ccu_telephone_v3bis ts ON ts.idUser = u.id
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN procuration_part pp ON pp.idClient = u.id
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN reexp_contrat rc ON rc.idCCU = u.id
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN client_refpm cr ON cr.id = u.coclico
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN
                        (SELECT ctp.idCCUSouscripteur , max(ctp.id) as idContratDGP
                        FROM contrats_part ctp
                        WHERE ctp.idCCUSouscripteur is not null and ctp.source = 'Digiposte' and ctp.statutContrat = '2' GROUP BY ctp.idCCUSouscripteur)
                        as ctp1 ON ctp1.idCCUSouscripteur = u.id
                group by u.id
);
```

this query takes too long, I want to simplify it

Comment: The only thing that looks VERY off here is that final `GROUP BY`. That is a logic to apply and then finally say "Only return distinct u.id and if any of these columns should contain different values for the same u.id in the multiple pre-aggregated rows, then just choose which ever one you want". That doesn't address your optimization question though, to which there is likely nothing to do be done in your sql. Your optimization should focus on indexing and the like.

Comment: The query is malformed and can only run in MySQL 5.x. All columns not mentioned in the `GROUP BY` clause should be aggregated in the select list.

Comment: Don't you have any indexes?  At least a PRIMARY KEY?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use "LEFT" unless the right-hand column is missing some rows and you want NULLs.  In particular, `contrats_part` looks like it can never be null.

These indexes may help:

```
ctp:  INDEX(source, statutContrat, idCCUSouscripteur,  id)
a:  INDEX(idUser)
t:  INDEX(idUser,  dateMaj, numero, principal)
m:  INDEX(idUser,  dateMaj, adresse, principal)
ads:  INDEX(idUser,  ligne4, ligne6)
ts:  INDEX(idUser,  numero)
ms:  INDEX(idUser,  adresse)
pp:  INDEX(idClient,  idOrigine)
rc:  INDEX(idCCU,  numero)
```

It *may* be better to make this change; I do not know for sure:

Instead of, for example,

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ts.numero SEPARATOR ';') as numerous,
...
LEFT OUTER JOIN  ccu_telephone_v3bis ts  ON ts.idUser = u.id
```

get rid of the JOIN and change the select part to

```
( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ts.numero SEPARATOR ';') as numerous
       FROM ccu_telephone_v3bis ts  WHERE  ts.idUser = u.id
)  as numerous,
```

Doing that to all the aggregates should let you get rid of

```
GROUP BY u.id
```

This

```
case when ctp1.idContratDGP is null then false else true end
```

can be simplified to

```
ctp1.idContratDGP is NOT null
```

Looking at that list of JOINs, I suspect the schema is "over-normalized".